# Queue up funciton if clicked multiple times in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopping-cart

I was making a button that submits an AJAX request to update shopping cart when clicked.

The problem is, if the user clicks a multiple times in quick succession, the script won't be able to update it (eg. clicked 10 times in 2 seconds, only added the item twice).

I wonder if there is anyway to queue up the ajax requests?

Comment: Instead you need to fix the roots of the issue: your server-side code need to be able to handle any amount of requests sent simultaneously in a thread-safe manner. Don't just pretend there is no issue, but fix it.

Comment: that is a good point, it's just I'm running testing with a remote server that's across the globe, so I'm getting like 500ms latency for each database query. I just want to make sure it queues up the request.

Comment: @JonathanChow take a look at the code below and see whether it makes sense for your application.

Comment: @JonathanChow That's not what zerkms said. The server-side code should be able to handle multiple requests all at once without them hurting each other. Even if both requests run at the same time!! i.e. getting the old quantity, adding one in the front end code, then saving it back will NOT work. What if two requests run at once?

Comment: @Ariel I'm sorry I don't really understand, are you saying if I'm getting multiple requests at the same time, I should be able to handle it on server side (eg. queue them on up server side)?

Comment: @JonathanChow Yes. (Normally to do this you use locks. Be *sure* to only lock the specific cart though, not all of them.) Or write lock-free code, what that means in your case is that the read and update of the quantity happen at the same time (normally only a database has the ability to do this, and you do it by doing the entire thing in a single SQL statement). Transactions are one way of implementing locks by using the database (you do SELECT ... FOR UPDATE), there are others.

Comment: @Ariel I've never heard of SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. Damn university doesn't teach things I need :P Thanks a lot, that helps a lot.

Comment: @JonathanChow To get you started: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html - although you could probably just google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a simple queue the following way:

```
var lock = false, queue = [];
$('#submitButton').click(function (event) {
    var data = ExtractRequestData(); // This function is what you do to get the data you want to send
    PerformRequest(data);
});

function PerformRequest(data) {
    if (!lock) {
        lock = true;
        $.ajax(// perform ajax request
            complete: function (data) {
                // Complete handler
                lock = false;
                if (queue.length > 0) {
                    PerformRequest(queue.shift());
                }
            }
    } else {
        qeueu.push(data);
    }
}
```

This guarantees you to execute the requests in order and one after another after each request has been completed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can queue up ajax requests, but I prefer to disable the button until the request finishes.

The browser will automatically queue up ajax requests, but does not guarantee the order, just that all will eventually execute.

If you need them to run in order I found http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/ via google which is a plugin that adds a queue to ajax requests and makes sure they run in order, and never more than one at a time.

For the disabled button, make sure to add a timeout to the ajax request, and if the request times out then reenable the button.